# Threaded Binary Search Trees Advantage

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, asymptotic-complexity

An explanation about Threaded Binary Search Trees (skip it if you know them):

We know that in a binary search tree with n nodes, there are n+1 left and right pointers that contain null. In order to use that memory that contain null, we change the binary tree as follows -

for every node z in the tree:

if left[z] = NULL, we put in left[z] the value of tree-predecessor(z) (i.e, a pointer to the node which contains the predecessor key),

if right[z] = NULL, we put in right[z] the value of tree-successor(z) (again, this is a pointer to the node which contains the successor key).

A tree like that is called a **threaded binary search tree**, and the new links are called **threads**.

**And my question is:**
What is the main advatage of Threaded Binary Search Trees (in comparison to "Regular" binary search trees).
A quick search in the web has told me that it helps to implement in-order traversal iteratively, and not recursively.

Is that the only difference? Is there another way we can use the threads?

Is that so meaningful advantage? and if so, why?
Recursive traversal costs O(n) time too, so..

Thank you very much.

Comment: Recursive traversal is `O(n)` time complexity, with an `O(logN)` space requirement (average case) and `O(N)` space requirement in the worst case. On the other hand, a threaded binary tree has an `O(1)` space requirement in the worst case, if the traversal is done iteratively.

Answer (score 5):

Non-recursive in-order scan is a huge advantage. Imagine that somebody asks you to find the value "5" and the four values that follow it. That's difficult using recursion. But if you have a threaded tree then it's easy: do the recursive in-order search to find the value "5", and then follow the threaded links to get the next four values.

Similarly, what if you want the four values that precede a particular value? That's difficult with a recursive traversal, but trivial if you find the item and then walk the threaded links backwards.

Comment: Yes, RDBMS's do that with their B-trees as well to support fast range scans.

Comment: What happens in case "5" isn't there in the tree? In an ordinary BST we stop recurring and return "key not found" on NULL child pointer, but a threaded tree has no NULL pointers (except in the leftmost and the rightmost node). I suppose one needs to detect a backwards pointer, as, say, at a node with `node.key == 4` we'd like to go right, but `node->right->key > 5` and `node->right->left == node`. Is that correct?

Comment: @CiaPan If "5" isn't there, then the recursive search wouldn't find it. The threaded tree doesn't have NULL pointers in the leaves, but it does have flags that tell you whether the pointers are threaded links or standard BST links. During search, you treat thread links as NULL pointers.

Comment: @JimMischel Aha, I got it. I've never seen a threaded tree before, so I only knew what was stated in the question, and the 'this was a null pointer' flags are not mentioned there. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of Threaded Binary Search Trees over Regular one is in Traversing nature which is more efficient in case of first one as compared to other one.

Recursively traversing means you don't need to implement it with stack or queue .Each node will have pointer which will give inorder successor and predecessor in more efficient way , while implementing traversing in normal BST need stack which is memory exhaustive (as here programming language have to consider implementation of stack) .